# LINQ to entities performance regarding where clause

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2005, linq-to-entities

Let's say i have a table in a database with 10k records. I dont need to actually use those 10k records anymore, but i still need to keep them in the database. That very table is now going to be used to store new data. So there's gonna be more records coming on top of the 10K records already present in the table. As opposed to the "old" 10K records, i do need to work with the newly inserted data. Right now im doing this to get the data i need:

```
List<Stuff> l = (from x in db.Table
            where x.id > id
            select x).ToList();
```

My question now is: **how does the `where` clause in LINQ (or in SQL in general) work under the covers?** Is the ENTIRE table going to be searched until `(x.id > id)` is true? Because let's say the table will increase from 10k records to 20K. It'd be a little silly to look through the entire 20 k records, if i **know** that i only have to start looking from a certain point.

I've had performance problems (not dramatic, but bad enough to be agitated by it) with this while using LINQ to entities, which i kinda don't understand because it should be no problem at all for a modern computer to sift through a mere 20 k records. I've been advised to use a stored procedure instead of a LINQ query, but i dont know whether or not this will boost performance?

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't there an option to show what query Linq is submitting to SQL Server? If not, can't you just set up a trace and look? And yes, I agree about the advice you're getting - at least with a stored procedure you have an opportunity to tune the query, see what is actually being asked of SQL Server, etc.

Comment: It seems you have other problems. Linq-2-sql will just return a normal select * where and with proper indexing this will not be signicifantly improved by a stored procedure. And either way, with 20K records the performance should be no problem at all! My guess is your performance problem is somewhere "down the line" and not in this part of the code

Comment: @AaronBertrand i have not tried that out yet, but i will check it out. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to behave just like a similarly worded SQL query would. The question is whether the overhead you're experiencing is happening in the query or in the conversion of the query to a list. The query itself as you've written should equate literally to:

```
Select ID, Column1, Column2, Column3, ... , Column(n+1)
From db.Table
Where ID > id
```

This query should be fairly fast depending on the nature of the data. The query itself will not be executed until it is acted upon, however. In this case, you're converting it to a list, which is the equivalent of acting upon it. I can't find the comment someone made to me about this practice, but I've found it too be quite helpful in keeping performance clean. Unless you have some very specific need, you should leave your queries as `IQueryable`. Converting them to lists doubles the effort because first the query must be executed and then the result set must be converted into an appropriate `IEnumerable` (List in this case).

So you have 2 potential bottlenecks. The simple query could be taking a long time to query a massive collection of data, or the number of records could be bottenecking at the poing where the List is created. Another possibility is the nature of `ID` in this case. If it is numeric, that will save you some time. If it's performing a text-based search then it's going to be heavier.

To answer your specific question, yes, it's going to search every record in the database and return all of the records that match the expression. *Edit: If the database has a proper index on the column in question, it will not search EVERY record but rather will use the index to perform the search. From comment from @Pleun.*

As for using a stored procedure, that's a load of hogwash, but it's a perfectly acceptable alternative. I have several programs that routinely run similar queries against a database with over 40 million records, and the only performance issue I've run into so far has been CPU usage when multiple users are performing rapid firing queries. To solve your specific issue, I'd recommend that you tune it a little in SQL Management Studio until the query you want returns to your interface with an acceptable speed. Then you can convert that query into a compatible Linq statement. As long as you leave it as an `IQueryable` it should exhibit similar results.

Comment: If ID is properly indexed, it will NOT search every record in the database.

Comment: Joel, thank you for the elaborate answer, i will look into the IQueryable vs ToList(). and @Pleun: so you're saying that if properly indexed, in my case, the search will "start" at the point where x.id > id ?

Comment: @Pleun: Yes, if it is properly indexed it will start at the first point that matches the expression. I'll post an edit to clarify.